# ThreadStart return value?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am re factoring some legacy code, and I have updated the Task.Execute method used in the ThreadStart statement below to be used in another context. However now it causes a compile error saying Task.Execute has the wrong return type.

Why is this and how do I work around it so I can keep my return value but also the ThreadStart?

```
ThreadStart start = new ThreadStart(Task.Execute);
Thread asyncThread = new Thread(start);
asyncThread.IsBackground = true;
asyncThread.Start();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return type of `ThreadStart` is `void`, so you must pass a method that returns `void`. If `Task.Execute` is non-void, you can use a lambda expression:

```
ThreadStart start = new ThreadStart(() => Task.Execute());
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to write a wrapper for your `Execute` method which does not return a value, as `ThreadStart` delegate expects a method with a `void` return type:

```
public static class Task
{
    public static int Execute()
    {
        //blah blah blah

        return 1;
    }

    public static void ExecuteWrapper()
    {
        Execute();
    }
}
```

Then:

```
ThreadStart start = new ThreadStart(Task.ExecuteWrapper);
Thread asyncThread = new Thread(start);
asyncThread.IsBackground = true;
asyncThread.Start();
```

Can the return value be safely ignored though? This often points to a design issue.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, and short wrapper (unless You wanted to remember the return value):

```
ThreadStart start = new ThreadStart(() => { Task.Execute(); });
...
```